# Amp and voltage effect on solenoid coil

Tags: power-supply, voltage, coil, solenoid

If I have battery of 7.4 V and 10 A = 74 watt connect to solenoid coil.

And if I have battery of 12 and 6 A = 72 watt (almost 74) connect to solenoid coil.

And they are under same situation (same ohm, projectile's weight, number of turns, etc.)

Will both push with same force?

What is the difference between higher voltage or higher current in same coil?

Should I run a higher voltage in my solenoid coil, or a higher current?

Comment: You need to know the resistance of your coil.

Answer (score 2):

The term used for determining the magnetomotive force of a solenoid is "[ampere-turns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampere-turn)" which alone should answer your question.

Think of it another way: your solenoid has a given resistance, if you apply two different voltages, which one will produce more current? Correct, the higher voltage.

\$I = E/R\$

With a given resistance (R), increasing voltage (E) will increase current (I) as well.

Your battery specifications are misleading, because batteries are not rated in both volts and amps. They may be rated in volts and ampere-hours (Ah), the latter of which is a measure of the battery's *capacity*.

It's possible that one of the batteries you are using has a high internal resistance, which might occur if the battery is of a particular chemistry that's unable to produce high current, or more likely a sign that the battery is discharged or faulty.

Answer (score 0):

Solenoids have very low DCR.  The battery is expected to have much lower ESR so the voltage does not drop significantly and this resistance decreases as the Ah rating increases.

Without any details I can only speculate your 12V battery is too weak for this load and perhaps you did not measure voltage before during and after the load test.

Although the your numbers appear similar in output power, they could be wrong and a solenoid always takes more current with higher voltage.  So I suspect the 12V battery must be dropping the voltage and dissipating a stressful heat inside around 4V so only 24W outside and 48W heat inside @ 6A

Answer (score 0):

The solenoid coil has a certain DC resistance, R, that depends on its construction (mainly the gauge and length of the coil wire). Ohm's law then determines the relationship between voltage across the coil, V,  and the current through it, I. You cannot independently choose both values. For example, if the solenoid resistance is 2 ohms, then your 7.4 volt battery will force a current of 7.4/2 or 3.7 amps through the solenoid. Your 12 volt battery will force a current of 12/2 or 6 amps. The force generated by the solenoid is proportional to the current through it. Thus the 12 volt battery will generate more force than the 7.4 volt battery simply because it causes more current through the solenoid coil (as determined by Ohms law: I=V/R).